# How to transfer Yoast SEO plugin data into advanced custom fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, yoast

My current site used yoast plugin for show meta data. But i want to deactivate the plugin and I want to transfer all meta details in to Advanced custom fields. Any idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WP All Export` plugin to export whole your preferred data, then use `WP All Import` plugin to import as ACF fields.

> URLs of plugins

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-export/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/